# HybridAuth keeps giving "User profile request failed. Most likely the user is not connected to the provider and he should to authenticate again."

Tags: codeigniter, hybridauth

I am trying to implement HybridAuth Login for facebook. but it keeps giving me the above error.I tried redirecting the user to the facebook login page again after this error occurs but this results in a loop.

Please help me.This is my code.

```
public function login($provider)
{
    try
    {
        $this->load->model('home_model');
        $this->load->library('HybridAuthLib');
        if ($this->hybridauthlib->providerEnabled($provider))
        {
            $this->service = $this->hybridauthlib->authenticate($provider);
            if ($this->service->isUserConnected())
            {
                $user_profile = $this->service->getUserProfile();  <-- error here
                $access_credentials = $this->service->getAccessToken();
                redirect("site.com/profile/".$user_profile->identifier,"refresh");      
            } else { // Cannot authenticate user
                show_error('Cannot authenticate user');
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $error = 'Unexpected error';
        switch($e->getCode())
        {
            case 0 : $error = 'Unspecified error.'; break;
            case 1 : $error = 'Hybriauth configuration error.'; break;
            case 2 : $error = 'Provider not properly configured.'; break;
            case 3 : $error = 'Unknown or disabled provider.'; break;
            case 4 : $error = 'Missing provider application credentials.'; break;
            case 5 : log_message('debug', 'controllers.HAuth.login: Authentification failed. The user has canceled the authentication or the provider refused the connection.');
             //redirect();
            if (isset($service)){
                $service->logout();
            }
            break;
            case 6 : $error = 'User profile request failed. Most likely the user is not connected to the provider and he should to authenticate again.';
                     break;
            case 7 : $error = 'User not connected to the provider.';
                     break;
        }


        if (isset($service))
        {
            $service->logout();
        }
        show_error($error);
        /*          redirect("www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?
        client_id=[APP_ID]
        &redirect_uri=site.com/hauth/login/Facebook
        &state=1
        &scope=publish_stream
        ","refresh");* <-- when try to use this. It generates a redirect loop from facebook to my site
    }
}
```

Comment: have you setup providers' keys?

Comment: @RaffaeleIzzia kindly explain the answer

Comment: what version of hybrid auth are you using? I literally have *almost* the same code in my hybridauth controller and mine works, but as I recall I had to modify the facebook class for it to work as facebook changed their api after the release of the version i was using